# How to install right package for deployment of Laravel app to Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I get the following error:

```
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to install system packages!
remote:  !     >   Problem 1
remote:  !     >     - Installation request for phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5 -> satisfiable by phpseclib/bcmath_compat[1.0.5].
remote:  !     >     - phpseclib/phpseclib 2.0.27 requires php >=5.3.3 -> satisfiable by php[7.1.33, 7.2.26, 7.2.27, 7.2.28, 7.2.29, 7.2.30, 7.2.31, 7.3.13, 7.3.14, 7.3.15, 7.3.16, 7.3.17, 7.3.18, 7.3.19, 7.4.2, 7.4.3, 7.4.4, 7.4.5, 7.4.6, 7.4.7].
remote:  !     >     - Installation request for phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5 -> satisfiable by phpseclib/bcmath_compat[1.0.5].
remote:  !     >     - phpseclib/phpseclib 2.0.27 requires php >=5.3.3 -> satisfiable by php[7.1.33, 7.2.26, 7.2.27, 7.2.28, 7.2.29, 7.2.30, 7.2.31, 7.3.13, 7.3.14, 7.3.15, 7.3.16, 7.3.17, 7.3.18, 7.3.19, 7.4.2, 7.4.3, 7.4.4, 7.4.5, 7.4.6, 7.4.7].
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.2.26
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.2.27
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.2.28
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.2.29
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.2.30
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.2.31
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.3.13
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.3.14
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.3.15
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.3.16
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.3.17
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.3.18
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.3.19
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.4.2
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.4.3
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.4.4
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.4.5
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.4.6
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.4.7
remote:  !     >     - don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.5|don't install php 7.1.33
remote:  !     >     - Installation request for phpseclib/phpseclib 2.0.27 -> satisfiable by phpseclib/phpseclib[2.0.27].
```

I have php 7.4.3. So far I've tried
`composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:~2.0`
and
`composer require phpseclib/bcmath_compat:1.0.5`
. I've also read [this thread](https://github.com/phpseclib/bcmath_compat/issues/1). However, I still have no idea how to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up needing to remove laravel/telescope in composer.json because it required moontoast/math, which required the phpseclib packages. Moontoast/math is outdated, which is probably why Heroku doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either follow

[lesterchan's solution on github](https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/154#issuecomment-433848353)

or in my case, remove `App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider::class` in config/app.php file and laravel/telescope in composer.json